# How to show file picker which pointed to application sandbox in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my application, all files are saved in app's sandbox documents: ~/Documents.
How can I let users to pick file from ~/Documents using UI like Document Picker which using for picking file from iCloud or external sources?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is good library to create custom file picker which pointed to application sandbox (Document directory)

https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser

Answer (score 2):

[Here is good library to create custom file picker which pointed to application sandbox (Document directory).](https://github.com/marmelroy/FileBrowser)